react-native-pdf-thumbnail 1.3.1 build app failed in React-Native 0.76.1
I have a react-native app using react-native-pdf-thumbnail that works perfectly in React-Native 0.75.4 but when I try to use the new React-Native version 0.76.1 and I got the following error during the build phase.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-pdf-thumbnail:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
  > Compilation error.

More details on error:
> Task :react-native-pdf-thumbnail:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: file:///Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/react-native-pdf-thumbnail/android/src/main/java/org/songsterq/pdfthumbnail/PdfThumbnailModule.kt:101:74 Type mismatch: inferred type is Bitmap.Config? but Bitmap.Config was expected

Do you have any idea?
